# Moq generate class declaration while using ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, moq

I am trying to unit test a 3rd party library which has many of interface definitions on their constructors.

For example;

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IOwnerDataProvider>().To<OwnerDataProviderFake>();
```

I had to create OwnerDataProviderFake manually since I would like not to use real implementation of it.

Is there any way to use Moq to create a fake implementation of this interface instead of creating manually?

For example something like;

```
kernel.Bind<IOwnerDataProvider>().To<Mock.GenerateFakeClassDefinition<IOwnerDataProvider>()>();
```

Comment: Try the MoqMocking extension. Ninject will then create a moq for most types you give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's the whole point of Moq (and mocking).  Check the [Moq Quick Start](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for more examples of creating mocked objects, but try this to get going:

```
kernel.Bind<IOwnerDataProvider>()
      .ToMethod(context => new Moq.Mock<IOwnerDataProvider>().Object);
```

This will create a new mock of the `IOwnderDataProvider` interface every time you get it from the kernel.

You'll likely want to configure it's behavior via calls to `Setup`, but without any more info from you I can't help much beyond that.

Comment: This already solved my problem, I will check through documentation for further details. Thanks.